# Array of structures- unreferenced local variable

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

Im trying to compile this and it says 
(43): warning C4101: 'work': unreferenced local variable

I am trying to array of Worker structures
                                                Write  4 functions
1.      one to input an array of Worker structures
2.      one to figure the earned for each Worker
structure in the array
3.      one to output the array of Worker structures
4.      one to count the number of workers who have worked overtime.  Return the answer through the function call

I cant delete work in int main() or else it wont compile at all, this is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


struct Worker 
{
int idNumber;
int hoursWorked;
double hourlyRate;
double earned;
};



// function prototypes
void input(Worker [], const int);
void earnings(Worker [], const int);
void output(Worker [], const int);
int over(Worker [], const int);


int main() {



int overtime;



//const int numWorkers = number;
//work[];
//work[numWorkers];




Worker work;
int numWorkers;

cout << "How many workers are there?";
cin >> numWorkers;

Worker * workers = new Worker[numWorkers];


input(workers, numWorkers);
earnings(workers, numWorkers);
output(workers, numWorkers);
overtime = over(workers, numWorkers);

cout << "The number of workers who worked overtime is " << overtime << endl;

delete[] workers;

return 0;
}
void input(Worker f[], const int numPeople) {

for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {

    cout << "Worker # " << i << endl;
    cout << "Enter the id number: ";
    cin >> f[i].idNumber;
    cout << "Enter the hourly rate: ";
    cin >> f[i].hourlyRate;
    cout << "Enter the hours worked: ";
    cin >> f[i].hoursWorked;
}
}

void earnings(Worker e[], const int numPeople) {

for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {

    if (e[i].hoursWorked <= 40) {

        e[i].earned = e[i].hourlyRate * e[i].hoursWorked;

    }
    else {
        e[i].earned = (40 * e[i].hourlyRate) + ((e[i].hoursWorked - 40 
((e[i].hourlyRate / 2) + e[i].hourlyRate));
    }
}

}

void output(Worker end[], const int numPeople) {

for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {

    cout << "-------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Worker # " << i << endl;
    cout << "Id number: " << end[i].idNumber << endl;
    cout << "Hours worked: " << end[i].hoursWorked << endl;
    cout << "Hourly rate: " << end[i].hourlyRate << endl;
    cout << "Earned: " << end[i].earned << endl;

}

}

int over(Worker o[], const int numPeople) {
int overWorked = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {
    if (o[i].hoursWorked > 40) {
        overWorked += 1;
    }
}

return overWorked;
}
```

Comment: `Worker work;` You are not using `work` anywhere.Then why don't you remove this.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  I agree with Gaurav, just delete Worker work  and fix the mismatched parentheses in earnings method.

Comment: On a side note: use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays

Answer (score 2):

Warning `unreferenced local variable` means, that you defined variable and never use it. And, since this is simply warning, it doesn't prevent the compilation or your code.You can simply remove the line `Worker work;`.

BTW, you have compilation error in this line:

`e[i].earned = (40 * e[i].hourlyRate) + ((e[i].hoursWorked - 40 
((e[i].hourlyRate / 2) + e[i].hourlyRate));`

maybe the bad formatting, when you post your question? Possibly this line should look like:

`e[i].earned = (40 * e[i].hourlyRate) + ((e[i].hoursWorked - 40) * ((e[i].hourlyRate / 2) + e[i].hourlyRate));`

Comment: I think this is what you meant e[i].earned = (40 * e[i].hourlyRate) + ((e[i].hoursWorked - 40) *
            ((e[i].hourlyRate / 2) + e[i].hourlyRate));

Comment: @RobKreger Thanks, your math looks more logical.